# I'm trying to install docker and its hangs at Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-xenial)

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-machine

[image]I'm using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04
to install docker, while providing sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce command its starts downloading unpacking files and hangs at
Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-xenial) ...

Can someone help me ?
Now even if I kill the process and do sudo apt-get upgrade it still hangs here